# Why do I get "Connection Refused" when attempting to connect to IPFS API using HTTP?

Tags: networking, api, curl, firewall, ipfs

Created a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 20.04 droplet and setup an IPFS server node in it based on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/pinata/how-to-deploy-an-ipfs-node-on-digital-ocean-c59b9e83098e).

If I run the following command in the server

> ipfs swarm peers

I get the expected results

[image]

In addition, according to [the documentation](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#getting-started)

> Every command usable from the cli is also available through the HTTP API. For example:
>
> ipfs swarm peers
>
> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/swarm/peers

so, as I try

- In Postman

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 164.92.254.19:5001

[image]

- In curl

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 164.92.254.19 port 5001 after 2295 ms: Connection refused

[image]

---

For reference, here's the firewall

[image]

and as you can see TCP 5001 is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a tip from the [Reddit user techiesaravana](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipfs/comments/rfe48b/comment/hoheoko/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) who says

> Hi, you have to edit ipfs config file you need to change the Address field to
>
> "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001"

I was able to solve the issue. To do so, I ran

```
ipfs config Addresses.API /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001
```

and then

```
systemctl restart ipfs
```

Now I get the expected result

[image]

[image]